# In a Hilbert space, every bounded and closed set is weakly relatively compact.

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, compactness, weak-convergence

My aim is to prove that in a Hilbert space, any bounded sequence has a weakly convergent subsequence. To prove this, I'm trying to prove that:

```
In a Hilbert space, every bounded and closed set is weakly relatively compact
```

I have tried it via Banach-Alaoglu theorem but I find it difficult as this theorem applies to the dual space with the weak-* topology and not the weak one. Anyway I have the feeling that there is an easier way to prove it.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: "any *bounded* sequence has a *weakly* convergent subsequence"

Comment: A (complex) Hilbert space is (anti) isomorphic to its dual. Doesn't that solve the problem?

Comment: @DavidMitra Thank you, typo corrected.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat I'm trying to prove it with the theorems that I know. I don't know why a Hilbert space is isomorphic to its dual. Is there another way?

Comment: Do you know Riesz representation for Hilbert spaces?

Comment: Yes, I know that one.

Comment: What I wrote is a 2-line-proof-corollary t Riesz rep!

Comment: That's right! So, my Hilbert space H is isomorphic to its dual and hence, using Banach-Alaoglu, the closed unit ball in H is compact (in the weak topology? I don't see this clear, I guess I don't have enough knowledge about weak topologies) and hence using some kind of translation, any closed bounded set is weakly relatively compact?

Comment: That sound right. The weak star topology is the same as the weak topology IIRC.

Comment: You need to show a bit more. The weak topology is in general not metrizable. So,   knowing that bounded closed sets are weakly compact does not immediately imply they are sequentially compact. This is true, but I imagine at the point you're at, you need to provide an argument (and then you may as well just prove your original statement (using a diagonalization argument, e.g.)).

Answer (score 3):

Banach-Alaoglu and Riesz theorem are an overkilling, even if I really like it as a proof. Moreover, your statement is true in general in reflexive spaces and it is usually known as the easy part of Eberlein-Smulian theorem. Recalling the following definitions,

> **Definition.** Let $X$ be a Banach space. $X$ is *reflexive* iff the canonical injection $J: X \to X''$, $\langle J, x \rangle_{X'',X} = \langle \cdot, x \rangle_{X',X}$, is surjective.

A fundamental result is

> **Theorem 1 (Kakutani).** Let $X$ be a Banach space. They are equivalent
>
> 1. $X$ is reflexive;
> 2. $B_X$ is weakyl compact.

From Kakutani's theorem follow

> **Theorem 2.** Let $X$ be reflexive, $M$ a closed linear subspace of $X$. Then $M$ is reflexive.
>
> **Theorem 3.** $X$ reflexive $\iff$ $X'$ reflexive.
>
> **Corollary 1.** Let $X$ be reflexive and $M$ a closed linear subspace of $X$. Then $X/M$ (quotient space) is reflexive.
>
> **Corollary 2.** $X$ reflexive and separable $\iff$ $X'$ reflexive and separable.

Now we can state

> **Theorem 4.** Let $X$ be reflexive and $\{ x_n \} \subseteq X$ a bounded sequence. Then there exist $x \in X$ and $\{ x_{n_k}\}$ s.t. $x_{n_k} \rightharpoonup x$ as $k\to\infty$.

*Proof*. Set $M = \overline{\mbox{span}_{\mathbb K}}\{x_n\}$. By Theorem 2, $M$ is reflexive and obviously is separable. Hence, by Corollary 2, $M'$ is reflexive and separable. Then $J(B_M) = B_{M''}$ is compact and metrizable with respect to the $\sigma(M'', M')$ topology, so there exists $\{x_{n_k}\}$ subsequence and $F = J(x)$ s.t. $J(x_{n_k}) \rightharpoonup J(x)$ when $k\to \infty$ with respect to the $\sigma(M'', M')$, i.e., by definition, $\langle J(x_{n_k}), f \langle_{M'',M'} \to \langle J(x_n), f \rangle_{M'',M'}$. Since $M$ is closed, $x \in M$ and $\langle f, x_{n_k} \rangle_{M',M} \to \langle f, x_n \rangle_{M',M}$ when $k\to\infty$. Thanks to the Hahn-Banach theorem, there exists $L \in X'$ s.t. $f := L_{|M}$ and hence we have $\langle L, x_{n_k} \rangle_{X',X} \to \langle L, x_{n_k} \rangle_{X',X}.$ $\square$

Now consider a Hilbert space $H$. The scalar product on $H$ induces a norm which satisfies the *parallelogramm identity* (trivial):

$$\| x + y \|^2 + \| x - y \|^2 = 2( \|x\|^2 + \|y\|^2)$$

for all $x,y\in H$. Such a norm is uniformly convex and hence, by

> **Theorem 5 (Milman).** Let $X$ be a Banach space. If $X$ is uniformly convex, then $X$ is reflexive.

we have $H$ is reflexive. So the previous Theorem 4 holds and your claim follows as a corollary of it.

I know your method was quicker, but I listed a few of results you would probably know, provided you can apply Banach-Alaoglou theorem. By the way, in the previous work there is no needing of knowledge of Hilbert spaces theory, except for the definition. In this sense, this is the easiest proof, even is longer.

**References.**

- Brezis, *Functional analysis, Sobolev spaces and partial differential equations*.
- Yosida, *Functional analysis*.

Comment: Very Helpful! Thanks!