# verify inf-compact function

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, compactness

> Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a real Hilbert space. A function $f \colon \mathcal{H} \to \mathbb{R} \cup \left\lbrace + \infty \right\rbrace$ is *inf-compact* if for any $r > 0$ and $\kappa \in \mathbb{R}$,
> \begin{equation*}
> \textrm{Lev}_{\kappa}^{r} \left( f \right) := \left\lbrace x \in \mathcal{H} \colon \left\lVert x \right\rVert \leq r , f \left( x \right) \leq \kappa \right\rbrace
> \end{equation*}
> is relatively compact set in $\mathcal{H}$ (A relatively compact set is the set which its closure is compact).

In particular, I am interested to check if the following function is inf-compact or not

> $$ f \left( x_{1} , x_{2} \right) := \dfrac{1}{2} \left\lVert x_{1} - x_{2} \right\rVert ^{2} , \forall \left( x_{1} , x_{2} \right) \in \mathcal{H}_{1} \times \mathcal{H}_{2} . $$

We can show that $\textrm{Lev}_{\kappa}^{r} \left( f \right)$ is always a closed and bounded set. Hence when $\mathcal{H}_{1} \times \mathcal{H}_{2}$ is a finite dimensional space, $\textrm{Lev}_{\kappa}^{r} \left( f \right)$ is a compact set and thus $f$ is inf-compact. However, for a infinite dimensional space we can not do the same. In fact, as I found we can only prove that ([$\textrm{Lev}_{\kappa}^{r} \left( f \right)$ is weakly relative compact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/643649/in-a-hilbert-space-every-bounded-and-closed-set-is-weakly-relatively-compact)). How can I conclude from this?

Comment: From where is the definition you cite at the beginning of your post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think $\operatorname{Lev}_\kappa^r(f)$ is relatively compact for your $f$ if one the Hilbert spaces (w.l.o.g. $\mathcal{H}^1$) is infinite dimensional, since the set $$\{(x_1,0)\in \mathcal{H}^1\times\mathcal{H}^2|\ \|x_1\|_{\mathcal{H}^1}\leq \sqrt{2\min{(\kappa,r)}}\}\subset \operatorname{Lev}_\kappa^r(f).$$
This set is basically the ball with radius $\sqrt{2\min{(\kappa,r)}}$ in $\mathcal{H}^1$, which is not compact (see e.g. [Is any closed ball non-compact in an infinite dimensional space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253081/is-any-closed-ball-non-compact-in-an-infinite-dimensional-space)).

Comment: many thanks. but am I corrected when I said that $f$ is inf-compact when $\mathcal{H}$ is finite dimension?

Comment: You are absolutely correct in that $f$ is inf-compact, if both Hilbert spaces are finite dimensional.